# O programa trava quando chega no while

Tags: java, algoritmo

Fiz um programinha básico sobre calcular potenciação, porém quando chega no `while` trava, e até o terminal eu tenho que reiniciar. Assim não consigo continuar o programa. Até tentei mudar a maneira do Scanner porém cheguei a conclusão que era o `while` mesmo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   
    int c = 0; //contador
    int p = 1; //potencia

    int a;
    int b;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Digite o valor da base:");
    a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Digite o valor do expoente:");
    b = input.nextInt();
   
    while (c != b){
         p = p * a;
         c = c++;
        
        }

    System.out.printf("A potencia de int %d como base e int %d como expoente eh: %d\n",a, b, p);
    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O maior problema é que o `c++` já está fazendo o incremento na variável, o `++` é um operador que causa efeito colateral e muda o valor da variável, então a atribuição do resultado nela mesma está fazendo algo indevido e causando problema.

Na verdade o código poderia ser melhor organizado e dar nomes melhores para as variáveis, assim pode evitar comentários.

Poderia usar um `for` mas preferi deixar assim porque poderia ser exigência do exercício.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite o valor da base:");
        int base = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o valor do expoente:");
        int expoente = input.nextInt();
        int contador = 0;
        int potencia = 1;
        while (contador != expoente) {
            potencia *= base;
            contador++;
        }
        System.out.printf("A potencia de int %d como base e int %d como expoente eh: %d\n", base, expoente, potencia);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/niL7dO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hdxqzxqd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Pow.java).

Comment: Na primeira linha onde está `C++` não seria `Java`?

Comment: Não :D Olha o código original da pergunta, tem um `c++` :)